# Example of an integer $n_0$ such that $1+\sum_{k=2}^{n_0} \zeta(k)^s=0$ has repeated roots

Tags: cv.complex-variables, sequences-and-series, examples, riemann-zeta-function, zeroes

After I was studying the exercise **Problem 4.20** from [1] I was inspired to ask about next problem, where $\zeta(k)$ denotes, for integers $k>1$, particular values of the Riemann zeta function. And $s=x+iy$ the complex variable.

> **Question.** Is it possible to find an integer $n_0\geq 2$ such that for $n=n_0$ the corresponding term of the sequence $$f(s)=1+\sum_{k=2}^n \zeta(k)^s\tag{1}$$ has a root of multiplicity $\geq 2$? **Many thanks.**

Thus (for each fixed integer $n\geq 2$) the function $(1)$ is a function of the complex variable $s$.

And we are asking about an example of $n=n_0\geq 2$ for which $(1)$  $$1+\sum_{k=2}^n \zeta(k)^s=0$$
has a zeroes/roots $s$  of multiplicity strictly greater than $1$.

### References:

[1] Valentin Boju and Louis Funar, *The Math Problems* $\mathcal{Notebook}$, Problem 4.20 in page 31/194, Birkhäuser, Boston (2007).

Comment: Many thanks to the user that upvoted my post, was generous.